# I/O operation on closed file on csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im working on python3 project and I am getting error when trying to write on CSV file.

```
with open('infile.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)


# manipulate the data

with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as fl:
    writer = csv.writer(fl)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Im  getting `I/O operation on closed file on csv python` issues. Do I need to create `outfile.csv` first? Im not sure?

Comment: both have same file handler f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using a context manager the infile gets closed when you come out of it scopes.

The solution is

```
with open('infile.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)


    # manipulate the data

    with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for row in reader:
             writer.writerow(row)
```

Edit Here is a more concise and efficient way

```
with open('infile.csv', 'r') as fin, open("outfile.csv" , "w") as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout) 
    for row in reader:        
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: more idiomatic is to open both in the same context manager. `with open('infile.csv', 'r') as fin, open('outfile.csv', 'w') as fout: # do stuff`

Comment: ya that is more concise and efficient

Comment: for multiple context managers it is better to use [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack)